# in, bei oder auf der Post(Bank)

Tags: word-choice

> Ich war in/auf der Post(Bank, Polizei)ю

Wie ist es richtig, wenn ich sagen möchte, dass ich eine Institution besucht habe?

Ist es umgangssprachlich zu sagen, dass ich z.B. BEI der Post oder der Bank war?

Answer (score 2):

Wir müssen hier unterscheiden zwischen Bank/Post und Polizei. Die ersten beiden bezeichnen sowohl eine Institution als auch ein Gebäude, die Polizei bezeichnet nur eine Institution (das Gebäude wäre z.B. die Wache).

In der Bank/Post: Im Gebäude.
Auf der Bank/Post: Auf dem Gebäude oder umgangssprachlich/regional für "bei".
Bei der Bank/Post: Bei der Institution.

Weiterhin kann "auf der Bank" noch "auf der Parkbank" meinen.

Bei der Polizei geht nur "bei der Polizei", auf und in gehen nicht, da diese sich auf ein Gebäude beziehen würden.
Allerdings wird umgangssprachlich hier meist "auf der Wache" statt "in der Wache" verwendet.

Comment: Hab mal die Umlaute korrigiert...

Comment: *Ich habe dafür zu wenig Geld auf der Bank*. Und trotzdem würde ich sagen, dass die Institution gemeint ist.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Danke, hab leider keine deutsche Tastatur hier. Rudy: Stimmt tatsaechlich, den Fall hab ich vergessen. Allerdings habe ich ein Konto bei der Bank, nicht auf; also ist Deutsch mal wieder sehr schwer. :)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Naja, das ist ja umgangssprachlich für "auf dem Bankkonto". Da kommt wohl das *auf* her.

Comment: @Dirk: Ein Konto bei, aber Geld auf der Bank.