# an, in oder bei der Straße

Tags: word-choice

Wir treffen uns morgen an/in/bei der ABCStraße.

Wir treffen uns morgen an/in/bei der ABCStraße 00. ( Wenn ABC ist ein Name und 00 ist eine Nummer einer Straße)

Wie ist das es richtig zu sagen, wenn man in der Nähe einer Adresse und wenn man in einem Gebäude mit einer bestimmten Adresse treffen möchte?

Ich bin jetzt an/in/bei der ABCSTRASSE.

Ist es richtig, wenn man damit meint, dass man auf der Straße ist?

Ich bin jetzt an/in/bei der ABCStraße 00.

In welchem Fall sagt man, dass man in der Nähe von einem Gebäude mit einer bestimmten Adresse und nicht drinnen ist?

Comment: Related [https://german.stackexchange.com/q/43737/](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/43737/) and [https://german.stackexchange.com/q/43741/](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/43741/)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice!